# JSON value '1' of type NSNumber cannot be converted to UIEdgeInsets in react-native ios version

Tags: react-native

Getting this error in my screen. How can I solve this. I am using react native 0.64.3 version.[image]

Comment: Can you show where in your code you're passing the number 1 as a prop?

Comment: I have a flatlist which is creating the issue, If I remove this I dont get to see the error.But I have to use flatlist. This is the code snapshot link: https://prnt.sc/wkuNQg_tglFw?fbclid=IwAR0FKh5p2lVi5nDrz8tuF7xrvoTxSFHioXnD3aKYULXXefGYLn-YuesSwxk